SNS not triggering Lambda with filter policy
The message that the my SNS Topic will publish to my lambda looks like this
{
    "eventId" : 005,
    "eventType" : "DeploymentEnd",
    "eventData" : {
        "deploymentId" : 1179729715,
        "deploymentType" : "FlipActivate",
        "environmentStageName" : "IhmEcoNvidiaJetsonABImage/bonser/Prod",
        "initiatingUser" : "bonser",
        "packagesChanged" : 443,
        "startTime" : 1440524895,
        "endTime" : 1440526045,
        "deploymentRequestId" : 183839041,
        "status" : "Failed",
        "description" : "Sync from EnvImprovement's Prod stage",
        "oldEnvironmentStageRevisionId" : 159539189,
        "newEnvironmentStageRevisionId" : 162163445,
        "fleetwide" : true,
        "blocking" : true,
        "revisionCommitted" : true,
        "newRevision" : true,
        "recordVersionNumber" : 33
    }
}

I want to add filter policy which will filter messages and trigger lambda only when the following conditions are fulfilled
I want to add an sns filter policy that looks something like this
{
  "eventType": [
    "DeploymentEnd"
  ],
  "eventData.status": [
    "Failed"
  ],
  "eventData.environmentStageName": [
    {
      "prefix": "IhmEcoNvidiaJetsonABImage"
    },
    {
      "prefix": "IhmEcoDeviceConfigSmoothAmbler"
    }
  ]

But the above json is not triggering my lambda
What is the correct way to do it?
I tried this
I want to add an sns filter policy that looks something like this
{
  "eventType": [
    "DeploymentEnd"
  ],
  "eventData.status": [
    "Failed"
  ],
  "eventData.environmentStageName": [
    {
      "prefix": "IhmEcoNvidiaJetsonABImage"
    },
    {
      "prefix": "IhmEcoDeviceConfigSmoothAmbler"
    }
  ]


If you remove the filter, is the Lambda function triggered? If so, keep adding back parts of the filter policy to identify which parts of it are preventing the Lambda invocation. Let us know what you discover!
